# When can I interchange $\liminf$ and integral?

Tags: functional-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Let $g_n:[0,T] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence.

When can I say that
$$\int_0^T \liminf_{n \to \infty} g_n(t) \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty}\int_0^T g_n(t)?$$
Under what circumstances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Fatou's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma). ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

you can say that :$\int_0^T \liminf_{n \to \infty} g_n(t) \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty}\int_0^T g_n(t)$ if $g_n$ is a sequence of Borel functions on $(\omega,G,t)$ , it's clear that your sequence : $g_n\geq0$ Then just to use the "Fatou’s lemma " , for information pleas see Theorem 1.1 page 1:http://pages.stat.wisc.edu/~doksum/STAT709/n709-4.pdf